# angular2 with type script

Tags: angular, typescript

I begin to learn angular I try to display data by categorie ;I get this data in service.ts:

```
getFoodsByCat(id :number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://livrer/api/menu/' +id)
    .map(
        (response: Response) => { return response.json().foods;
         }
    );}
```

And Iam looking for create a function to passe categorie_id in it manually because I have 7 categories 1 until seven. I miss somthing in THE FUNCTION onGetFoodsByCategorie(id) i dont know what:

```
export class FoodsComponent implements OnInit {
foods: Food[];
id : number;

  constructor(private foodService: FoodService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  } 
onGetFoodsByCategorie(id){
this.foodService.getFoodsByCat(this.id)
.subscribe(
(foods: Food[])=> this.foods = foods,
(error : Response)=> console.log(error)
);
  }
```

how to do this logic to work like that  :

```
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(2)">Burger</li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(3)">Sandwichs</li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(4)">PIZZAS</li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(5)">Salades</li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(6)">Desserts</li>
<li (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(7)">Boissons</li>
```

Because it display nothing.

Comment: Do logic for what? What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Please be clear in your question

Comment: i miss somthing in THE FUNCTION onGetFoodsByCategorie(id)  i dont know what.

Comment: Try `ng-bind-html-unsafe` to achieve your logic

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
this.foodService.getFoodsByCat(this.id)
```

by

```
this.foodService.getFoodsByCat(id)
```

And remove the `id` field from your component, since it's useless.

Comment: @nizet thank you for your response ,I get this Errors :EXCEPTION: Error in ./FoodsComponent class FoodsComponent - inline template:16:10 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.  I fetch data with :<app-food *ngFor= "let food of foods" [food]="food"></app-food>

Comment: What you're getting back from your service is not an array as you think it is. Use your debugger, look at the response body in the network panel of your dev tools.

Comment: @nizet how to fetch data from this response

Comment: Use TypeScript (Object.keys, etc.) to transform this object into something that the view can use.

Comment: thanks I resolve this prob in my backEnd I send data in array.